# Determine the iterated sum of the digits of $88^{88}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

First I use the fact that if the sum of the digits of a number is divided by $9$ then the number is divided by $9$.

So : $88^0\equiv 1\ [9]$

$88^1\equiv 7\ [9]$

$88^2\equiv 4\ [9]$

$88^3\equiv 1\ [9]$

Then $88^{88}=\big(88^{29}\big)^3\times88^{1}\equiv 7 \ [9]$

I try to see the possibilities : we have $88^{88}\le 10^{176}$ which means that the sum of the digits is bounded by $9\times176=1584$. Then the sum of the sum is bounded by $1+45+81+36=163$. Then the sum of the sum of the sum is bounded by $1+54+27=82$. Then the sum of the sum of the sum of the sum is bounded by $8+9=17$.

So it could be $7$ or $16$ but $1+6=7$. That's why it's $7$ the final answer.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: To find the digital sum, you will *have* to compute $88^{88}$ explicitly. The reason being that taking remainder modulo $9$ does not at all simplify the calculation of the sum,it only provides a bound.

Comment: 88 doesn't look very compatible with the decimal system.. So I suspect there is no easy way round it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the iterated digit sum?  That's $7$, for the reason you mentioned.  The answer to your question is $745$ by computer, but I don't see any short cut to seeing that.

Comment: @lulu by iterated you mean "the sum of the sum of the sum" ?

Comment: @Maman Indeed. This is the kind of sum (along with the mod-11 sum) that we use to check hand-written calculations.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.  If you iterate, you'll get the original number $\pmod 9$ (well, unless it was divisible by $9$, in which case you get $9$, not $0$).

Comment: Given the edit, your original solution looks optimal to me.  You just want to compute $n\pmod 9$ , which you do.

Comment: An observation: you can easily get a upper bound for the iterated sum of the digits which is better than $17$. Since, by definition of iterated sum, you stop if and only if the result has exactly one digit, an upper bound is $9$.

Comment: I'm very confused by your edit.  Before when you thought you wanted the actual sum you calculated that the iterated sum would be 7.  Now that you do know that you want the iterated sum, why aren't you stopping when you get $88^{88} = 7 \mod 9$.  You are done.  Why are you going further?  What do you think you need to solve.

Comment: @Maman Why do I see two digits in "$10$" ?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli yes of course the maximal bound of one digit is $9$.

Comment: It's stronger than the number if divisible by 9 if the iterated sum of the digits is 9.   It's the number is congruent to the iterated sum modulo 9.  In other words, you've got $88^{88} = 7 \mod 9$ then the iterated sum is ....7.  That's it.  I have no freaking idea what you think bounding the iterated sum means.

Comment: Why not asked on the first prime of five digits that appeared in expand the power proving first that it exists? I have this whim. The downvoters for Dr. Sonnhard Graubner are the same upvoters for this post? Anyway a hope could be given by transforming in $2^{264}(10+1)^{88}$?

Comment: "Why not asked on the first prime of five digits that appeared in expand the power proving first that it exists?"  ???????  "Anyway a hope could be given by transforming in $2^{264}(10+1)^{88}$"  What do you mean?

Comment: @fleablood I ignored this property, that's why I use several bounds...

Comment: @fleablood: the comment was for the original post, before it is edited and changed radically.

Comment: I'm still curious how it would work.  What do you mean by "transforming" and how do we tranform 8 to 11?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually the iterated sum of the digits will be a single digit number. A number is congruent to the sum of its decimal digits mod $9$, so every iterated sum will be congruent to $7$ mod $9$ (assuming your calculation is correct). Therefore the final iterated sum of the digits is $7$.

Comment: Why do you exclude $16$ ?

Comment: @Maman The sum of the digits of $16$ is $7$.

Comment: because you should add the one and the six in 16 to get 7.

Comment: Indeed no problem

Comment: ascertain using answer given by Dr Sonnhard Graubner